# Why Picasso loads image faster if Placeholder is not used Android?

Tags: android, picasso

I used picasso as image library for my application. Images were loading a bit slowly so i decided to remove placeholder and it started loading faster.

How come if placeholder is not there its loading faster. But problem is if I remove placeholder. Before loading image it squeezes that area and once image loads it takes proper area filled with image.

My Imageview code below:

```
<com.wallie.imagview.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageone"    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/border_image_view"
                android:padding="1dp" />
```

Picasso code i used earlier (loads image a bit slower ):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.image_loading)
                    .into(imageView);
```

Picasso code i used now (loads image faster):

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url)    
                    .into(imageView);
```

But problem is it squeezes space for image without placeholder and my spinner for all images get in one place.

Comment: Try to use Android Query instead Picasso check : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: I have already published app and entire code is around picasso. I working on improving performance so without placeholder images loader faster but until image loads that area of imageview is squeezed instead i want to show that space with spinner

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143157/android-picasso-placeholder-and-error-image-styling