# Images takes too much time to show in recyclerView in android. Is there any way to cope this issue

Tags: android, image, firebase, android-recyclerview

Greeting to all
My application is almost Completed.But I am facing a problem that my application takes too much time to load image.

Comment: are you downloading the image from url?

Comment: yes sir. i am downloading the images through url from firebase

Comment: Can we see some code... Also, are you downloading the images on the UI thread? If so, don't and use a third party library or using AsyncTask

Comment: Try Glide or Picasso library this will help you out.

Comment: sir i am using picaso

Comment: if you are using large images its going to take time to download, then resize it correctly

Comment: can you tell me correct size. yes i am sending full size image and downloading full size image too .

Comment: You problem is that you are loading full size images that may be larger than the View their being displayed in. It can quite a bit of time to downloaded, @ManzoorHussain decoded and displayed the images, based on network conditions on both sized and the devices specs. The size is based on the ImageViews width, we cannot give you the correct values, it's something you need to test manually to find the correct trade off of resolution and image size, based on acceptable display time and memory.

Comment: @ManzoorHussain General advice for StackOverflow: you should provide relevant snippets of code, layouts, etc. Have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, have a detailed look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ManzoorHussain If you are using Picasso then downgrade the resolution of image

Comment: To solve network latency problem, aside from providing an image with the right size, you can use a placeholder while loading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143157/android-picasso-placeholder-and-error-image-styling#22786818

Comment: @ManzoorHussain like that Picasso.with(context).load(business.getPhoto()).placeholder(R.drawable.default_business).resize(300, 300).centerCrop().into(imageView);

Comment: Take a read here https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @JRamesh thank you sir. its works really amazing just solved the problem now loaded all images :)